# Expression of Bohr Magneton

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields

I was studying the chapter "Magnetic field in Material" and I got something called Bohr Magneton. It says as follows -

> Atoms with unpaired electrons possess an intrinsic magnetic dipole moment whose magnitude is of the order of $\mu_B = \frac{eh}{4\pi m}$. Here $\mu_B$ is called the Bohr Magneton.

Please anyone explain in deeply and give a idea how I can derive that expression of $\mu_B$.

Comment: Compute the magnetic moment of a classical spherical shell with charge $e$ rotating on its axis with angular momentum $\hbar/2$. You should get within a factor of 2 of the Bohr magneton. (Note: Electrons are not actually rotating spheres, but this classical analogy should help you understand how the magnetic moment and the angular momentum of a charged system are related.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the basic Bohr model, you have an electron in a circular orbit
with velocity $v$ at radius $r$.

The angular momentum is $L=mvr$.

The magnetic moment is given by the product of the area and the current. The area is $\pi r^2$  and the current is  $ev\over 2 \pi r$ so $\mu={evr \over 2}$

Comparing these, the $v$ and $r$ stuff all cancels and $\mu={e \over 2 m} L$. The magnetic moment is proportional to the angular momentum. This is a classical result, it holds for any charge in a circular orbit.

But it's specially useful because $L$ is what is quantised: $L=n \hbar$. That means the magnetic moment and its projection on the $z$ axis are quantised 
in units of ${e \hbar \over 2 m}$. Called $\mu_B$ for short.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome explaination.